# Timestamp Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

How Convert the time   16:00:00  or 08:00:00  HH12:MI AM  format in oracle query

I try   `TO_CHAR ('16:00:00', 'HH12:MI AM')`  but it shows no AM / PM .

Please check

Answer (score 3):

Well, it works fine:

```
select to_char(to_date('16:00:00', 'hh24:mi:ss'), 'hh12:mi am') from dual;
```

The result is:

```
04:00 pm
```

Isn't it what you want?

Comment: Correct. `TO_CHAR()` expects a date (or a number) not a string.